# Bundler is not installed/Path error when trying to run OpenProject setup

Tags: ruby, git, bundler, openproject

I don't have much experience with this type of thing, but hope someone could help. I believe I have bundler installed, but when I run the `setup.rb` file to install OpenProject, I keep getting an error that bundler isn't installed. When I run `gem list` and bundle list, it generates a list for both. What am I missing?

```
$ setup.rb
==> Installing OpenProject...
==> Checking Ruby Version
==> It seems you are not running the recommended patch level.
==> To avoid unexpected problems we would recommend to install 'ruby 1.8.7 (2012-10-12 patchlevel 371)'
==> Checking Bundler
The system cannot find the path specified.
==> It seems bundler is not installed. Please install bundler before running set
up.rb.
==> For bundler and more information visit: http://gembundler.com/
==> Something went wrong :(
==> Installation aborted.
```

Comment: What version of OpenProject are you trying to install? And in what environment are you experiencing those problems?

Comment: Actually, could you do the following things in your terminal: `ruby -v`, `bundle -v` and if you got your copy of OpenProject via git, `git log -n 1 --oneline HEAD`?

Comment: Depending on the use-case for your OpenProject installation, you might consider using the newer `feature/rails3` branch. It is currently in the beta-phase, but uses a modern version of ruby/rails. The OpenProject developers currently migrate everything to this new branch.